# How to select duplicates based on specific columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to count the distinct values based on two columns and copy the cleaned up table based on distinct values for only these columns.

The original table has 5 columns.

```
b_id  | col1  | col2 | col3 | col4 
1     | c11   | c21  | c31  | c41
2     | c21   | c22  | c23  | c24
3     | c31   | c22  | c23  | c24
4     | c41   | c42  | c44  | c44
4     | c41   | c52  | c53  | c54
6     | c61   | c62  | c63  | c64
6     | c61   | c72  | c73  | c74
7     | c71   | c72  | c73  | c74
```

I would like to select only:

```
b_id | col1  | col2 | col3 | col4 
1     | c11   | c21  | c31  | c41
2     | c21   | c22  | c23  | c24
3     | c31   | c22  | c23  | c24
4     | c41   | c42  | c44  | c44
6     | c61   | c62  | c63  | c64
7     | c71   | c72  | c73  | c74
```

as b_id & col1 had duplicates. I don't mind if duplicates are or are not on col2, col3 and col4.

I tried this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 
new_table

CREATE TABLE 
new_table

AS (

select distinct 
b_id
, col1

from 
old_table

WHERE
col2 IN (val1, val2, val3, val4)
    AND col4 = xxx

);
```

but this selects distinct values that I need, but only these two columns and not the rest of the columns... :-/

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I need it for Redshift

Comment: anyone can please help here?

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:

```sql
select distinct b_id, col1,max(col2),max(col3),max(col4)
from old_tables
group by b_id, col1;
```

(as long as you don't care for which value will be taken from col2-col4)